# DataGridView FormattedValue is blank?

Tags: winforms, c#-2.0

I'm struggling getting a certain column within my DataGridView to display things right. It had been working and I must have broken something subtly, now all I get is an empty string. Does anyone know why this might be?

```
// this inherits from DataGridView
this.Rows.Add(new object[] 
{
    "test",
    new CustomType("A", "1")
});

CustomType()
{
   ...
   public override String ToString()
   {
      return this.String1 + ":" + this.String2;
   }
}
```

The result of such a thing is my Row.Cells[1].Value is "A : 1". However the FormattedValue is always blank...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I managed to find the cause of this... Unfortunately it was an annoying designer change whereby it lost the information that the column was bound to when I removed a different control from there.

This means that the databinding was not set, and hence it didn't know how to display the value.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell if your way is incorrect, but you seem to be doing it differently than [the API reference for DataGridView.FormattedValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.formattedvalue.aspx) would suggest.

Did you try it that way?

Comment: That page is using the 'FormattedValue' and parsing the result just to update an aggregated label. It isn't detailing about adding rows to the DataGridView.